# VBA "If < Then" function not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that sums time values for a week (dblTotal), this total is then added to column 'H' on the last day of the week.

However for one of the weeks the weeks time value only totalled to "0.0972222222222222" (02:20:00)

```
dblTotal = "0.0972222222222222"
```

The following piece of code is giving me a headache:

```
    If dblTotal > "1.875" Then
        Range("I" & (i - 1)).Value = dblTotal - "1.875"
        Range("H" & (i - 1)).Value = "1.875" - preTotal
    Else
        Range("H" & (i - 1)).Value = dblTotal - preTotal
    End If
```

When this runs it shows that dblTotal is Greater than 1.875 ? ..

Please let me know if I'm missing something silly here, I've tried using formatting on the values but feel as though I'm shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs because VBA modifies `0.0972222222222222` to `9.72222222222222E-02` (which is equal), but when you compare this value with string (`"1.875"`), your `dblTotal` casts to string too. So, when you compare two strings:  `"9.72222222222222E-02"` and `"1.875"`, first one would be greater.

Try to modify your code by casting to `Double` and changing `"1.875"` to `1.875`:

```
If CDbl(dblTotal) > 1.875 Then
    Range("I" & (i - 1)).Value = dblTotal - 1.875
    Range("H" & (i - 1)).Value = 1.875 - preTotal
Else
    Range("H" & (i - 1)).Value = dblTotal - preTotal
End If
```